# 'maildev' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to use maildev in a springboot application. I'm using intellij program.

using the terminal, I install the maildev like this:

C:\Users\msys\Desktop\spring_start>npm install -g maildev

"spring_start" is my project name

after installing it, the following appear in the terminal

> npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
> npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@3.1.8: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
> npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3
> .2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
> C:\Users\msys\AppData\Roaming\npm\maildev -> C:\Users\msys\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\maildev\bin\maildev
> maildev@1.1.0
> updated 1 package in 6.095s

but when I'm trying to run "maildev" command like this:

C:\Users\msys\Desktop\spring_start>maildev

the following error message appears:

'maildev' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. So I found a tricky way to get past the **'maildev' is not recognized as an internal or external command** issue.

So here is what I did.

1. I installed as an administrator maildev globally through the cmd.
2. I went to `C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm` where Your_User_Name is your own.
3. Clicked on maildev.cmd
   The terminal will open with something like this: `

   `MailDev webapp running at http://0.0.0.0:1080

   MailDev SMTP Server running at 0.0.0.0:1025`

Finally, In your browser, you can open the web application through 127.0.0.1:1080